# ASP.NET Removing Items from a list array by checking for certain value

Tags: asp.net

So I am reading a text file which may or may not end with some lines ending 9999999999999999999999999

which are just extra lines to make up a batch...im reading in the file like this

```
var lines = 
 File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\EmployeeExpenseReimbACH_20111214.txt");
```

How can I loop through this and remove the lines with 9999999's? and then end up with an array without them basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

var path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\EmployeeExpenseReimbACH_20111214.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(x => !x.EndsWith("99999"));
```

Comment: And if the line only has `999`?

Comment: OP stated that the lines end with `9999999999999999999999999`. And I assume he'd be able to determine whatever argument he needs to supply to `EndsWith` to make sure any lines will be removed that need to be. Why should I make the answer more complicated than required?

Comment: Yes, definitely dive into LINQ. It can make life so much easier sometimes. Glad I could help!